# Do I have to split up Lodash orderby calls to make it work?

Tags: typescript, sorting, lodash

I'm trying to sort some data in my front-end client code but lodash is acting weird.

None of the examples I find use data in an interface, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Assume an example where I want to sort the products by isInPriceList (descending), listorder (descending), name (ascending).

See my stackblitz example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lodash-playground-kbtjbg

```
interface IProduct {
    name: string;
    isInPriceList: boolean;
    listOrder: number;
}

...add some data

const sortedData = _.orderBy( data, p => [ p.isInPriceList, p.listOrder, p.name ], [ "desc", "desc", "asc"]);
```

This fails to sort the data in the order specified, however, this works:

```
let correctlySortedData = _.orderBy( data, p => p.name, "asc");
correctlySortedData = _.orderBy( correctlySortedData, p => p.listOrder, "desc" );
correctlySortedData = _.orderBy( correctlySortedData, p => p.isInPriceList, "desc" );
```

I assume that there is something wrong with the second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter should be an iterator resolving to an array of the names (strings) of the parameters to order by like so:

`const sortedData = _.orderBy( data, ['isInPriceList', 'listOrder', 'name'], [ "desc", "desc", "asc"]);`

see documentation example: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy

Comment: Awesome! I do not like having to insert the names of the properties as strings, is there a way around this?

Comment: Try `const sortedData = _.orderBy( data, [p => p.isInPriceList, p => p.listOrder, p => p.name], [ "desc", "desc", "asc"]);
`
It should do the trick.

Comment: Wow, actually found a bug doing that!